# Receiving image through USB to embedded device via USB CDC

Tags: usb, stm32, embedded, communication

I am trying to send images through the USB port to my stm32f7 eval board. I have taken pictures from webcam and send it by the code below

```
    import time
    import NumPy
    import cv2
    import serial

    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
    vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)

    ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM8',
    baudrate=921600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
    )

    #encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90]
    #result, encoded_img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)

    while True:
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor( frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY )
    flattened_img = numpy.ndarray.flatten( gray_img )
    ser.write(data=flattened_img)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('Q'):
    break
```

It is better for me to take images in grayscale and bitmapped.
I think this part is not causing the problem, but I only get 64 bytes each time according to the debugger

[debugger section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usAym.png)

I still could not figure out what is wrong with the embedded side. USB Full Speed can work at 12Mbits/s but I can't even receive an image, what can I do to receive images fully?
This is the project link -> https://github.com/Emreiris/Personal_Embedded_Software_Projects/tree/master/Project

Comment: The serial port has no concept of a packet, i.e. not concept of a start and end of your image. So it's normal that you receive it in chunks. The most likely chunk size is 64 bytes as that's the USB packet size. But it can be smaller as well. It's probably best if you first transfer that number of bytes (image size) and then the image data. Then you know how much data to expect on the receiver side. But you will still have to deal with several chunks.

Comment: @Codo thanks, I will try this method for sure.